# PDO - Insertion (INSERT INTO...) code doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, database, date, pdo

I'm trying to insert the current date/time to the database as the last time the user logged in. For some reason this doesn't work.
Other insertion scripts running on the very same page work well, and the connection is ok.
I use the same syntax to insert other stuff throughout the whole site, so I don't get what's wrong.
I can guarantee that the `else` part is being executed when I'm entering my password.

Here's the piece of code I am talking about.

```
if(!$pwVer){ 
     // code to execute if the password is incorrect.
} else {

    $dateT = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    $up_date = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_user_test (user_last_login) VALUES (:l_login)");
    $up_date->bindParam(':l_login', $dateT);

    $up_date->execute();

    validateUser($userid); //sets the session data for this user


    header("Location: cart.php");
    $con = null;
    die();
}
```

**Some background:**

- $pwVer returns `true` if the password is correct.
- both `tbl_user_test` and `user_last_login` are written exactly as they're in the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the table `tbl_user_test` have only the `user_last_login` column? If you don't insert some info like `user_id`, what dose this table pretend to be?

Comment: Try put `var_dump($up_date->errorInfo());` after the `$up_date->execute();` line, and tell us what it says.

Comment: @xdazz thanks! LOL I completely forgot that this is supposed to be a user specific thing... I should've added a `WHERE` part!

Comment: No, actually this doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to insert the current date/time to the database as the last time the user logged in. For some reason this doesn't work.

There is no error visible in your code, so it should be executed. One possible problem could be that PDO is in silent mode, which doesn't tell you what or if an error has occured. Set PDO to fail with an exception.

Also, there's no need to construct the current date yourself; you can use SQL's `NOW()`.

```
<?php
$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
try {
    $up_date = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_user_test (user_last_login) VALUES (NOW());");
    $up_date->execute();
}
catch( Exception $e ) {
    echo $e; exit;
}

header("Location: cart.php");
$con = null;
die();
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem thanks to your answer :) I think the problem was that I didn't define which row I actually want to update. So I used your code syntax and changed the sql to an `UPDATE` + `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try NOW() for the current date time ?

Answer (score 2):

Once check with this

```
$up_date->bindParam(':l_login', $dateT, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```